# can command volumes unto themselves -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([The Object-Oriented Thought Process (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330164)):

> I cannot state too strongly that this book does not teach Java, C# .NET, and VB .NET or UML, all of which can **command volumes unto themselves**. It is my hope that this book will whet your appetite for other OO topics, such as OO analysis, object-oriented design, and OO programming.

How do you guys understand that phrase?

Comment: Those subjects each would take several or many books to describe. "Command unto themselves" is flatulent writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Command** here is a slightly unusual usage, related to definition 2 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/command); it means, in this context, to require or to take up.

A **volume** is a single book which forms part of a greater piece of writing which is composed of several individual books; for example, very large dictionaries or printed encyclopaedias are often divided up into volumes, with each volume labelled "Volume 1", "Volume 2" etc. The word *volume* also implies a particularly large book.

In this case, the phrase "**command volumes unto themselves**" means "take up several (large) books in and of themselves (ie. alone)"; what the author is saying is that each of the programming languages he mentions could take several books to teach, and that the book (The Object-Oriented Thought Process) does not claim to teach them.

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of "command" is to deserve something. It's probably most often used with the word "respect" or similar ideas, as in, "Mr Einstein commands respect", meaning, he deserves respect because of the great work he has done. Or, "These warnings command our attention", meaning, we should pay attention to these warnings.

In this case, "command volumes unto themselves" means that these subjects deserve books specifically about them. The subjects are too big to be dealt with as side issues along the way to discussing the author's immediate subject. He wants to teach Object Oriented Programming, not Java and C#.